# Высота родительского div по высоте дочернего при позиционировании

Tags: css, html

Здравствуйте. Имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
<div class="общий контейнер">

<div class="картинка"></div>

<div class="контейнер">
<div class="фото"></div>
<div class="список"></div>
</div>

<div class="текст"></div>

</div>
```

Стили:

```
.картинка{display:block;float:left;width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.контейнер{display:block;float:left;width:100%;min-height:440px;height:1px;}
.фото{display:block;float:left;width:206px;height:auto;position:relative;border:3px solid #339966}
.список{display:block;float:right;width:394px;height:100%;position:relative;}
```

Наглядная схема:
[image: как код отображается по умолчанию]
Наглядная схема при увеличении кол-ва текста в списке:
[image: как код отображается при увеличении списка]
Допустим список имеет min-height:350px или auto...
Как сделать так, чтобы при увеличении текста в списке - он не залезал на текст?
Т.е. див-контейнер автоматически принимал высоту див-список.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Можно жестко задать `height` и добавить `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: Если правильно понял вопрос, `height:1px;` у контейнера нужно убрать

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память что бы флоаченый элемент не вылезал за контейнер контейнеру нужно overflow выставить. И да, height 1px нужно убрать
Либо псевдоэлемент с clear both поставить

Comment: К сожалению ни один из предложенных вариантов не работает... жестко задавать высоту не вариант, т.к. див-список должен менять высоту и отталкивать див-текст вниз...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.pic {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 640px;
  min-height: 440px;
  border: 3px solid #339966;
  position: relative;
}

.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 206px
}

.list {
  float: right;
  width: 394px;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <div class="pic"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То, что нужно!